# Actionscript 3: Create dictionary inside class?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, dictionary, public, var

I'm trying to transform my actionscript 3 code from the timeline, which I previously used, to packages.

I need to define some dictionaries in the beginning of the code.

But when running the following code inside my class, actionscript returns an error.

```
public var S_USA:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    S_USA["x"] = -299;
    S_USA["y"] = -114;
    S_USA["bynavn"] = "New York";
```

This is the error: "1120: Access of undefined property S_USA.

---

EDIT: Posting the entire code:

```
package 
{
import fl.motion.MatrixTransformer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Dictionary;
import flash.display.Shape;
import fl.transitions.Fly;
import fl.motion.MatrixTransformer;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.geom.Matrix;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import fl.controls.List;

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    public static var bg_width = 980;
    public static var bg_height = 541;
    public var spImage:Sprite;
    public var mat:Matrix;
    public var mcIn:MovieClip;
    public var mcOut:MovieClip;

    public var externalCenter:Point;
    public var internalCenter:Point;

    public var scaleFactor:Number = 0.8;
    public var minScale:Number = 0.25;
    public var maxScale:Number = 10.0;

    /*public static var startList:List;
    public static var sluttList:List;*/
    public var bynavntxt:TextField;
    public var intervall:TextField;
    public var create_route:SimpleButton;
    public var confirm_button:SimpleButton;
    public var beregn_tid:SimpleButton;

    public static var S_Norway:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    S_Norway["x"] = -60;
    S_Norway["y"] = -183;
    S_Norway["bynavn"] = "Oslo";

    public static var S_Australia:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    S_Australia["x"] = 307;
    S_Australia["y"] = 153;
    S_Australia["bynavn"] = "Sydney";

    public static var S_China:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    S_China["x"] = 239;
    S_China["y"] = -98;
    S_China["bynavn"] = "Beijing";

    public static var S_South_Africa:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    S_South_Africa["x"] = -26;
    S_South_Africa["y"] = 146;
    S_South_Africa["bynavn"] = "Cape Town";

    public static var S_Brazil:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    S_Brazil["x"] = -210;
    S_Brazil["y"] = 73;
    S_Brazil["bynavn"] = "Rio de Janeiro";

    public static var S_USA:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    S_USA["x"] = -299;
    S_USA["y"] = -114;
    S_USA["bynavn"] = "New York";

    public static var S_France:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    S_France["x"] = -79;
    S_France["y"] = -135;
    S_France["bynavn"] = "Paris";

    // ------------------------------------------------------

    public static var Flyplasser:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    Flyplasser["USA"] = S_USA;
    Flyplasser["Norway"] = S_Norway;
    Flyplasser["South Africa"] = S_South_Africa;
    Flyplasser["Brazil"] = S_Brazil;
    Flyplasser["France"] = S_France;
    Flyplasser["China"] = S_China;
    Flyplasser["Australia"] = S_Australia;

    public function Main()
    {
        // ------------------------------------

        startList:List = new List();
        sluttList:List = new List();
        bynavntxt:TextField = new TextField()  ;
        intervall:TextField = new TextField()  ;
        create_route:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton()  ;
        confirm_button:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton()  ;
        beregn_tid:SimpleButton = new SimpleButton()  ;

        this.addChild(startList);
        this.addChild(sluttList);
        this.addChild(bynavntxt);
        this.addChild(intervall);
        this.addChild(create_route);
        this.addChild(confirm_button);
        this.addChild(beregn_tid);
        // -----------------------------------------
        // We use the ctrl and shift keys to display the two different cursors that were created on the stage.
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler);

        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, mouseCoordinates);

        trace("Main spawned");
        // --------------------

        this.width = bg_width;
        this.height = bg_height;

        // --------------------

        for (var k:Object in Flyplasser)
        {
            var value = Flyplasser[k];
            var key = k;
            trace(key);
            startList.addItem({label:key, data:key});
            sluttList.addItem({label:key, data:key});
            var airport:flyplass = new flyplass(key,Flyplasser[key]["bynavn"]);
            airport.koordinater(Flyplasser[key]["x"], Flyplasser[key]["y"]);
            this.addChild(airport);
        }

        var mcOut = new OutCursorClip();
        this.addChild(mcOut);

        var mcIn = new InCursorClip();
        this.addChild(mcIn);

        startList = new List();
        this.addChild(startList)

        sluttList = new List();
        this.addChild(sluttList)

        bynavntxt = new TextField;
        this.addChild(bynavntxt)

        intervall = new TextField;
        this.addChild(intervall)

        create_route = new SimpleButton;
        this.addChild(create_route)

        confirm_button = new SimpleButton;
        this.addChild(confirm_button)

        beregn_tid = new SimpleButton;
        this.addChild(beregn_tid)
```

Comment: OK, It worked when I added `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you setting this data inside Constructor or function?

**EDIT:**

Hm, where to start...

1) You know that the trick with static is not gonna work if you'll create more than 1 instance of class? In this case if you have only 1 Main class it's gonna work, but omg... Imho it's not nice to store data in static vars...

2) If you already declared:

```
public var bynavntxt:TextField;
public var intervall:TextField;
```

later just do

```
bynavntxt = new TextField()  ;
intervall = new TextField()  ;
```

no need for type in there.

3) Later in Main you have something like:

```
var mcOut = new OutCursorClip();
this.addChild(mcOut);

var mcIn = new InCursorClip();
this.addChild(mcIn);
```

Why are you declaring new variables with same name but without Type?

Waaaaaay up you have:

```
public var mcIn:MovieClip;
public var mcOut:MovieClip;
```

so those variables are already declared. By declaring them once again you are creating local ones. Beware!! The ones from the top would be null after that.

Comment: Below "public class Main extends MovieClip" and above the function. Not sure where to call it :)

Comment: Best to do it in constructor or one of the functions. You should EDIT your question and paste more code from this class so we can be sure.

Comment: Now I added some code. I fixed the dictionary problem. But now I'm probably doing something wrong in adding the buttons and textfields. Line 95 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type flash.text:TextField to an unrelated type Class.

Answer (score 0):

1) Fill the dictionary inside the Constructor (I seen by comments you have done this already).

2) you have already assigned type to bynavntxt with `public var bynavntxt:TextField;` you should not be doing it again with `bynavntxt:TextField = new TextField();` just `bynavntxt= new TextField();` will do.

This is the same with all other variables on similar type.

3) Make sure this class is going to be your "Document Class"/"Compiled Class" otherwise you will not have access to the 'stage' variable yet. To make sure you will have access to the stage variable you can always do:

```
/* Inside Constructor */
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onAddedToStage);

/* Outside Constructor */
private function _onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, _onAddedToStage);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyHandler);
}
```

Again, if this is going to be the compiled class, this can be skipped.